# Не получается обновить локальный репозиторий из GitHub в Visual Studio

Tags: github, git-pull

Работаю над одним и тем же проектом дома и на работе через надстройку GitHub в Visual Studio. Опыта нет, прочитал только пару статей в интернете на эту тему.
Дома делаю commit и через push отправить проект на GitHub.
На работе команда pull не позволяет обновить проект, появляется сообщение:

> Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit, stash, or
>   undo your changes before retrying.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде бы TeamExplorer советует откомментить код на работе, чтобы не потерять после слияния. Так как я работаю один над проектом, то все варианты кода, которые меня интересуют - уже на GitHub, меня устраивает полное удаление оставшегося локального варианта на работе.

Что надо по шагам сделать, чтобы установить на рабочий компьютер код с гитхаба так как он там есть?

Comment: Он говорит, что у вас есть не зафиксированные локальные изменения. Сделайте commit перед pull

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете выполнить для обновления Вашего репозитория:

```
git commit -m "Your commit text"
git pull
```

Либо удалить текущую директорию репозитория и повторно его клонировать с GitHub:

```
git clone example.com
# example.com - Remote repo url
```

Answer (score 0):

я так понял, что если Вам **не нужны те лишние "незакоммиченные" локальные изменения, которые сейчас у Вас на работе и Вы не хотите их коммитить**, то пропишите `git reset --hard HEAD`. эта комманда уберет все незакоммиченые изменения и Вы "вернетесь" в состояние самого последнего коммита (`HEAD`). после этого смело делайте `pull`